# How to forcibly show the Smart App Banner on Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, smartbanner

I just added a [Smart App Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) to my site. It already showed one time, but I want to show it again for development purposes. As Apple says:

> When the user returns to the webpage, the banner won’t reappear.

So how do I avoid this "cooldown" that the banner receives?

Comment: Use a private browser window?

Comment: May be clearing the cookies and history of safari will help you.

Comment: Private window didn't do it and I already tried clearing the cache + cookies for my site.